# AWS Powershell authorization problems

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am building a custom module for people inside my company so they can work with AWS resources.
In the module I have a function that allows them to assume a certain role based on their active directory account.
It looks roughly like this:

```
function Use-Role {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage="Sandbox, Dev")]
        [string] $Account="Dev",
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage="operator, migrator")]
        [string] $Role="operator",
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage="eu-west-1, eu-west-2")]
        [string] $Region="eu-west-1"
    )
    $accountId = If ($Account -eq "Dev") {"123456"} Else {"67890"}

    Set-AWSSamlEndpoint -Endpoint "some_endpoint" -StoreAs endPoint -AuthenticationType NTLM

    if ($Role -match "operator") {
        Set-AWSSamlRoleProfile -StoreAs "SAML-$Account-BackupOperator" -EndpointName endPoint -RoleARN "arn:aws:iam::$($accountId):role/SAML-$Account-BackupOperator" -PrincipalARN "arn:aws:iam::$($accountId):saml-provider/ADFS"
        Initialize-AWSDefaults -ProfileName "SAML-$Account-BackupOperator" -Region $Region
    }
    elseif ($Role -match "migrator"){
        Set-AWSSamlRoleProfile -StoreAs "SAML-$Account-DbMigrator" -EndpointName endPoint -RoleARN "arn:aws:iam::$($accountId):role/SAML-$Account-DbMigrator" -PrincipalARN "arn:aws:iam::$($accountId):saml-provider/ADFS"
        Initialize-AWSDefaults -ProfileName "SAML-$Account-DbMigrator" -Region $Region
    }
}
```

When user imports module and uses this function, authorization is not working as expected. He/she is not getting access to resources they should and other similar problems.

When I run the same code:

```
Set-AWSSamlRoleProfile -StoreAs "SAML-$Account-BackupOperator" -EndpointName endPoint -RoleARN "arn:aws:iam::$($accountId):role/SAML-$Account-BackupOperator" -PrincipalARN "arn:aws:iam::$($accountId):saml-provider/ADFS"
Initialize-AWSDefaults -ProfileName "SAML-$Account-BackupOperator" -Region $Region
```

directly from a powershell terminal it works fine and all the permissions are okay.

Any pointers how to debug this, what might it be?

Comment: I've checked your code and there's nothing wrong with the logic, so I wonder if this is some issue with the AWS cmdlets, but its hard to be sure without being able to test directly. I did find this, does it seem relevant at all to you?: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=250506

Comment: I do think it is a bug in the SDK. Have been investigating this for a couple of days and it seems that `Initilize-AWSDefaults` and `Set-InitilizeCredentials` don't have correct behavior when called inside the function from the within the module. Also storing the role credentials under a profile name that doesn't match the role name seems to cause another bug :(